# How to overlay text on ion-item in Ionic 4

Tags: html, ionic4, angular9

I have a list as shown in the below image. As i click on the plus icon on each item,i will be calling a rest api to update the database. As i get a response, i want to overlay a success text message with transparent black background for few seconds as shown in the image.

[image]

Could anyone please guide me on how to achieve this? Can we use css or any angular material to achieve this?

below is the code.

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="3">
        <ion-img width="80" height="80" [src]="item.imagePath"></ion-img>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="7" >
       <ion-label class="item-name">item.name</ion-label>
       <ion-label class="item-price">item.cost</ion-label>
       <ion-label class="item-date">item.date</ion-label>        
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="2">
       <ion-icon class="select-icon" name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
   </ion-card>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
  add(item) {
    item.showMessage = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      delete item.showMessage;
    }, 3000);
  }
```

```css
.success-message {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: rgba(00,00,00,0.7);
    z-index: 1;
}

ion-card.showMessage { 
    .success-message {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

```html
 <ion-card *ngFor="let item of items" [class.showMessage]="item?.showMessage">
    <div class="success-message">Added to your coupon list.</div>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="3">
        <ion-img width="80" height="80" [src]="item.imagePath"></ion-img>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="7" >
       <ion-label class="item-name">item.name</ion-label>
       <ion-label class="item-price">item.cost</ion-label>
       <ion-label class="item-date">item.date</ion-label>        
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="2">
       <ion-icon class="select-icon" name="add-circle" (click)="add(item)"></ion-icon>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
   </ion-card>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... Will try out and update you. But one clarification,  Will div tag fully overlay on the ion item?